# Trouble integrating gRPC with OpenSSL in Yocto Project

Tags: openssl, grpc, yocto

I'm facing difficulties integrating gRPC with OpenSSL in my Yocto Project build. I've tried various approaches, including setting the OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR and using pkg-config, but the build still fails with errors related to OpenSSL.

Here's a simplified snippet from my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake

find_package(OpenSSL 3.0.8 REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB 1.2.13 REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC 1.50.0 REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(proto)
```

I'm using Yocto Project and want to ensure that gRPC uses the OpenSSL from the openssl-native package rather than the host system (debian bullseye: openssl 1.1.1w).

Could you please share your insights or provide guidance on the correct configuration how to use openssl-native version in my build

I have added already `openssl-native` to my `DEPENDS` section within my recipe (.bb)

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

I've attempted several approaches to integrate gRPC with OpenSSL in my Yocto Project build, including:

- Setting DEPENDS = "openssl-native" in my Yocto recipe.
- Experimenting with pkg-config and find_package in the CMakeLists.txt file.
- Manually setting OpenSSL paths in the CMakeLists.txt file.
- Verifying the host operating system (Debian Bullseye) and OpenSSL version (1.1.1w).

I expected that with these configurations, the build process would use the openssl-native package from Yocto instead of the host system's OpenSSL. However, I'm still encountering issues related to OpenSSL during the build.

```
| CMake Error at /home/user123/dev/project/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-linux/project-appls/0.1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fd559eea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
|   Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
|   system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "1.1.1w", but
|   required is at least "3.0.8" (found
|   /home/user123/dev/project/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-linux/project-appls/0.1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fd559eea-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypto.so,
|   )
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/user123/dev/project/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-linux/project-appls/0.1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fd559eea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
|   /home/user123/dev/project/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-linux/project-appls/0.1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fd559eea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:599 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
|   Cap2Server/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
|
|
| -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
| See also "/home/user123/dev/project/build/tmp/work/cortexa53-linux/project-appls/0.1.0+gitAUTOINC+69fd559eea-r0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/user123/dev/project/build/../metalayers/meta-project/recipes-extended/project-appls/project-appls_git.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2671 tasks of which 2670 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

Comment: `fails with errors related to OpenSSL` Can this error be shared, or should we imagine it?

Comment: @skandigraun I have added the missing output/error message

Comment: Right, `system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "1.1.1w"` this looks wrong. I guess you get this when you set the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` explicitly, right? What happens if you don't set it?

Comment: I do not set the var OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR explicitly. Compile works, when I use the SDK that is created via `bitbake -c populate_sdk`. Build fails only if I build the sw from within yocto, e.g. via `bitbake my-project`

Comment: Do you use some binaries from openssl during compilation, or are you trying to link against its headers/libraries? If the latter, you should add `openssl` without the `-native` prefix to the `DEPENDS` variable. (Well, both can be present, but the non-native should be there at least)